# HTTP Get - Python vs Spring Rest Template

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, spring, spring-boot

I am consuming a rest service using the code below -

```
r = requests.get(url=uril)
```

The above code returns the error below -

> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
>   certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))

However when I consume the same endpoint using Spring RestTemplate , I am able to successfully consume the service without passing any certificates.

Can you please let me know why there is a difference in behavior of these clients?

Answer (score 0):

Spring implies Java and Java comes equipped with an up to date trust store out of the box, which is then used by Spring. Maybe Python does not include such functionality out of the box, which means you have to do some extra preconfiguration of the client you use to perform the request. See documentation on http.client.HTTPSConnection.